# Problems with array. Java

Tags: java

I started learning java yesterday and this is the first time i'm using array. This is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class array 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int num[];
        num = new int[5];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        System.out.println("Insert 5 numbers:");
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1);
        {
            System.out.print("Insert the " + i + "° number: ");
            num[i] = input.nextInt();   
        }
        System.out.print("The numbers you entered are: ");  
        for(i = 0; i < 5 ; i = i + 1)
        {
            System.out.println(num[i] + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

When i try to run it i get this problem:

Insert 5 numbers:

Insert the 5° number: 1

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at array.main(array.java:14)

Comment: Your code aren't supposed to loop the 5th index, since i < 5 the last value is 4

Comment: Typo. `for(i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1);` Remove the semicolon at the end of the line.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch:  There's more to that typo...

Comment: @Makoto There's nothing wrong, per se, with reinitializing `i` in the second `for` loop. Better, imo, to point out the advantages of `i < num.length` over hardcoded magic numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

1. You have a semicolon at the end of your loop.  That will cause the loop to run until `i = 5` and you're kind of stuck with that value now.  Remove it.
2. `i` will *remain* 5 after the first loop for the same reason as above.  Declare and initialize `i` inside of your `for` statement.

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1) {
       // the rest of your block
   }
   ```

Comment: I feel so stupid... . Thanks for the help!